# How to add a link to each node of d3 radar chart?

Tags: html, d3.js

I have integrated radar-chart-d3 in my project and i want to add a link to each node of it so that onclick of it i can display the record details.please help.
 [you can see the demo here](http://bl.ocks.org/tpreusse/2bc99d74a461b8c0acb1)[image]

Comment: You need to add an `onclick` event handler to the elements for that.

Comment: Tanx for your good advice dear Lars but Where exactly i need to add onclick as i am new to d3 and javascript ??/

Comment: On the elements that you want to be "active" -- use `.on("click", function() { /* handler */ })` on the selection that contains those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the radar chart implementation you are using is black boxed, I'd add the links after it renders:

```
// this "circles" are where you want your links
svg.selectAll('.circle').each(function(d,i){

  // get the parent of each circle, we'll append the link to this
  var par = d3.select(this.parentNode);

  // create the link and text
  par.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.google.com")
    .attr("target","_blank")
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ (d[0].x) +","+ (d[0].y) +")") // where to place it!
    .text("this is a link");
});
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/X1yEuP7iYQw9L7cSDZyH?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks Mark very much. your answer could help me. And how to add different link for each node.?

Comment: @jones, add them to you data and read them out of it.  Updated example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/X1yEuP7iYQw9L7cSDZyH?p=preview